# How run task if scheduled task run too long

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm using windows scheduler to run .bat file every one and a half hours.
The .bat files contain code that executes Sisense build one by one (there is a pause between each build in the order they won't run in parallel).

.bat code example :

```
@echo off
start /wait /d "C:\Program Files\Sisense\Prism" psm ecube build filename="C:\Users\Games.ecube" 
start /wait /d "C:\Program Files\Sisense\Prism" psm ecube build filename="C:\Users\Netomedia.ecube"
start /wait /d "C:\Program Files\Sisense\Prism" psm ecube build filename="C:\Users\AffiliatePixel.ecube"
@end
```

Each line starts different build with wait between them, the whole .bat file runs approximately 60 min while the schedule is every 90 min.

The problem is that in some cases one of those builds can get stuck and run hours till I manually kill some process in Task Manager.
I'm looking for a way to run a command that kills the process if the task runs over X min

I tried to use the kill option in task scheduler but it only restarts the schedule it can't kill the stucked process in Sisense.
I tried the option of removing the /wait and adding TIME OUT to KILL process after X min

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\Sisense\Prism" psm ecube build filename="C:\Users\Games.ecube"
TIMEOUT 10 & REM Waits 10 seconds before executing the next command
"C:\Program Files\Sisense\Prism" psm ecs stop
```

It works but the problem is that it will always wait the time I set in time out, even if the job was finished after a few seconds

Does anyone have any suggestion what I can do in the .bat file to kill the process after X min (for example 90 min )

Will appreciate any help,

Dima K

Comment: Well, this is quite difficult in batch; probably it would help to switch to [tag:powershell]... Anyway, I think it would help to start every process with a known [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier), then you poll whether these processes still run until a certain limit is reached... Nevertheless, this question is too broad for this site, maybe it should be migrated to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)...

Comment: newly created tasks run with a priority level below normal. you may export the task, edit the xml file and change priority from 7 (below nomal) to 4 (normal priority). then import the xml task file.

Comment: Must agree with @aschipfl - this is definitely beyond what a windows batch file can or should do. You're looking to develop something quite elaborate and it will be much more approachable with Powershell, or even Node.js/.NET/Python or any other high level language you're comfortable with..
However, I do suggest to investigate why builds get stuck, in addition to having this workaround.